# For loop or apply to save simulation results in a vector?

Tags: r, loops, simulation, apply

My code is for a simulation of 100 coin flips where if you lose your 10 dollar stake you are bankrupt (ie net win/loss reaches -10 within 100 flips, each flip is a 1 dollar bet).  I want to run 500 times and then save the profit/loss results into one vector.  I have my code mostly working for one flip, although I figure it might not be the most efficient way - would it be best to add a for loop or apply?

```
n=100
total.profit=c()
game.cashflow = cumsum(2*rbinom(n,1,prob=0.5)-1)
  if(length(game.cashflow[game.cashflow==-10])>0){
    game.profit=-10}else{
      game.profit=game.cashflow[1000]}
```

I want to save the results in a total.profit vector.

Comment: Have a look on `replicate()`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Something like this?

```
flipit <- function(n) {
    res <- sample(c(-1,1),n,replace=TRUE)
    ifelse(any(cumsum(res)<=-10),"bust",sum(res))
}

replicate(500,flipit(100))
```